# VBA add connection points to a shape

Tags: vba, visio

How do I add connection points to a shape?

I began this project adding regular rectangles to the page and using AutoConnect to connect them which worked perfectly because each connection created a new connection point on the rectangle. When I switched to rounded rectangles new connection points were not created and the connectors ended up overlapping each other.

I add rounded rectangles like this...

```
        Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop Application.Documents.Item("BASIC_U.VSS").Masters.ItemU("Rounded rectangle"), 0, 0
```

I AutoConnect like this...

```
        Dim vsoConnectorShape As Visio.Shape
        Set vsoConnectorShape = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes("Dynamic connector")
        vsoConnectorShape.CellsU("LineColor").Formula = "rgb(" + CStr(red) + ", " + CStr(green) + ", " + CStr(blue) + ")"

        shp1.AutoConnect shp2, visAutoConnectDirNone, vsoConnectorShape
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add connection points by adding rows to the shape's connection points section (visSectionConnectionPts).
Code would look like:

```
Dim NewRow as Integer
NewRow = shp1.AddRow( visSectionConnectionPts , visRowLast, visTagDefault)
shp1.CellsSRC( visSectionConnectionPts, NewRow, visX).formula = "Width*0.5"
shp1.CellsSRC( visSectionConnectionPts, NewRow, visY).formula = "Height*0.5"
```

This code adds a new connection point to shp1, and sets the point in the center of the shape.